# Mask and Category Bits still allowing collision Box2d

Tags: c#, box2d

From my understanding, in Box2d, objects will collide with another object if the other object's category is in the mask.

I have set up a really simple scene where I have a square that should fall through the floor. For testing purposes I have made it so the mask and the category are completely different on the square and floor like below

```
FilterData cubeFilter = new() { CategoryBits = 0b0001, MaskBits = 0b0010 };
FilterData floorFilter = new() { CategoryBits = 0b0100, MaskBits = 0b1000 };
```

However, when the MCVE is run, the cube still lands on the floor rather than falling through.

Why are the two objects still colliding?

Full MCVE

NuGets

```
Install-Package Box2D.NetStandard -Version 1.0.3
Install-Package Box2D.Window -Version 1.0.3
```

Code

```
using Box2D.Window;
using Box2DX.Collision;
using Box2DX.Common;
using Box2DX.Dynamics;
using System.Threading;

namespace Box2dMcve
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            AABB aabb = new();
            aabb.LowerBound.Set(-20, -10);
            aabb.UpperBound.Set(20, 110);

            World world = new(aabb, new Vec2(0.0f, -9.81f), false);

            BodyDef cubeDefinition = new();
            cubeDefinition.Position.Set(0, 70);

            PolygonDef cubeFixture = new();
            cubeFixture.SetAsBox(5, 5);
            cubeFixture.Friction = 0;
            cubeFixture.Restitution = 0;
            cubeFixture.Density = 1;
            FilterData cubeFilter = new() { CategoryBits = 0b0001, MaskBits = 0b0010 };
            cubeFixture.Filter = cubeFilter;

            Body basicCube = world.CreateBody(cubeDefinition);
            basicCube.CreateFixture(cubeFixture);
            basicCube.SetMassFromShapes();

            BodyDef floorDefinition = new();
            floorDefinition.Position.Set(0, 20);

            PolygonDef floorFixture = new();
            floorFixture.SetAsBox(20, 5);
            floorFixture.Friction = 0;
            floorFixture.Restitution = 0;
            FilterData floorFilter = new() { CategoryBits = 0b0100, MaskBits = 0b1000 };
            floorFixture.Filter = floorFilter;

            Body floor = world.CreateBody(floorDefinition);
            floor.CreateFixture(floorFixture);
            floor.SetStatic();

            Thread windowThread = new(() =>
            {
                SimulationWindow game = new("Physics Simulation", 800, 600);
                game.UpdateFrame += (_, _) => { world.Step(0.02f, 8, 3); };
                game.SetView(new CameraView());

                DrawPhysics physicsDrawer = new(game);
                physicsDrawer.AppendFlags(DebugDraw.DrawFlags.Aabb);
                physicsDrawer.AppendFlags(DebugDraw.DrawFlags.Shape);

                world.SetDebugDraw(physicsDrawer);

                game.VSync = OpenTK.VSyncMode.Adaptive;
                game.Run(60, 0);
            });

            windowThread.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In case it is a bug, I have created an issue on the GitHub page for the .NET Standard implementation of Box2D. [Issue](https://github.com/benukhanov/box2d-netstandard/issues/28)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I hadn't set up a contact filter for the world. I think I just assumed it would do this by default.

Adding the line `world.SetContactFilter(new ContactFilter());` fixes the issue.